# Is this topology discrete?

Tags: general-topology

If a topology $\tau$ is strictly finer than cocountable topology and lower limit topology, then $\tau$ is discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove or disprove.

Comment: What is lower limit topology?

Comment: Lower limit topology is given by $\tau_{l}=\lbrace G\subset \mathbb{R}:$ for each $x\in G, $there exists $\epsilon >0 $ such that $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset G\rbrace$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call $\tau_S$ the Sorgenfrey topology, i.e. the topology generated by the base $\mathcal B_S=\{[x,x+\varepsilon)\mid x\in\Bbb R,\varepsilon>0\},$ and let $\tau_c$ be the cocountable topology on $\Bbb R,$ i.e. $\tau_c=\{U\subseteq X\mid X-U\text{ is countable}\}.$

If $\tau$ denotes the smallest topology containing $\tau_S\cup\tau_c,$ then $\tau$ has as a base all the intersections $U\cap V,\ U\in\mathcal B_S,\ V\in\tau_c.$ In other words, $W$ is a neighborhood of its element $x$ if there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $[x,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq W\cup Q$ where $Q$ is countable. This shows that $\{x\}$ is never a neighborhood of $x$ in $\tau,$ since $\{x\}\cup Q$ is countable. So $\tau$ is not discrete.